# How to assign value of a formula (that contains a variable) to another variable

Tags: excel, vba

I've to assign an algebraic formula that contains a variable (i for example) to another variable (say a).

I'm probably not using the right syntax. I've searched but couldn't find relevant answers.

```
Dim i As Long, a As Long
For i = 1 To 30
    a = SIN(RADIANS(i))
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes("sketch_1").Duplicate
        .IncrementTop i
        .IncrementRotation a
    End With
Next i
```

Is there also a way to directly enter the formula next to `.IncrementRotation` as opposed to having seperate variable "a" to do this job?

Comment: Edit your question and post the formula

Comment: Added my code. Please review.

Comment: Does it do what you expect? If not, then what is it not doing?

Comment: It doesn't apply value of the formula to a. instead it is giving me an error "object doesn't support this type of property of method".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Excel formulas in VBA using `WorksheetFunction`

```
a = Sin(WorksheetFunction.Radians(i))
```

Comment: getting an error "object doesn't support this type of property of method.

Comment: My mistake -there's a `Sin` function in VBA